# GlusterFS rebalancing volume failed

Tags: glusterfs

We are using GlusterFS 3.7.11 for distributed/replicated volume. originally the volume was formed from 4 bricks each on one dedicated node. we added 4 nodes to our design and in order to extend the volume capacity we added 4 bricks (each on one of the newly added nodes), so we ended up with a volume of 8 bricks (4 x 2 - replica 2). As far as best practice goes it is recommended to rebalance the volume by first fixing the layout and then migrating the data, so I started fixing the layout, after several hours the fix-layout completed succesfully. when trying to migrate the data, the rebalancing task failed after brief seconds. the crash report regarding the failed rebalancing is a follows:

```
   pending frames:
   frame : type(0) op(0)
   frame : type(0) op(0)
   frame : type(0) op(0)
   patchset: git://git.gluster.com/glusterfs.git
   signal received: 4
   time of crash: 
   2016-06-08 01:03:09
   configuration details:
   argp 1
   backtrace 1
   dlfcn 1
   libpthread 1
   llistxattr 1
   setfsid 1
   spinlock 1
   epoll.h 1
   xattr.h 1
   st_atim.tv_nsec 1
   package-string: glusterfs 3.7.11
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-    gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(_gf_msg_backtrace_nomem+0x92)[0x7fb81f1d75e2]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(gf_print_trace+0x31d) [0x7fb81f1f36cd]
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36cb0)[0x7fb81e5d5cb0]
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11f3b)[0x7fb81e975f3b]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(inode_ref+0x19)[0x7fb81f1f7e99]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(loc_copy+0x4a)[0x7fb81f1d59ca]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-   gnu/glusterfs/3.7.11/xlator/cluster/distribute.so(dht_local_init+0x4b)  [0x7fb8194d38db]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-  gnu/glusterfs/3.7.11/xlator/cluster/distribute.so(dht_lookup+0x91)[0x7fb8195087d1]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(syncop_lookup+0x1a2)[0x7fb81f21c102]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glusterfs/3.7.11/xlator/cluster/distribute.so(gf_defrag_fix_layout+0x89)[0x7fb8194db6c9]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glusterfs/3.7.11/xlator/cluster/distribute.so(gf_defrag_start_crawl+0x469)[0x7fb8194dd059]
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(synctask_wrap+0x12)[0x7fb81f218972]
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x49800)[0x7fb81e5e8800]
```

I can't really say where the issue is ..., i would really appreciate some input on this matter.

Thanks,
N

Comment: It is a very specific issue, I think your best bet is to reach GlusterFS mailing list at gluster-users@gluster.org or [here](https://www.gluster.org/mailman/listinfo/gluster-users)